# Envoy/Istio as reverse-proxy to explicit IP

Tags: envoyproxy, istio

I'd like to route like this (nginx pseudo-config):

```
server_name fou.example.com;
location "/Forskning" {
  upstream https://185.102.32.26/;
}
location "/" {
  upstream http://fou-web.fou.svc.cluster.local;
}
```

How do I do this with VirtualService, Gateway, ServiceEntry etc etc? Obviously I need to preserve the domain name.

Comment: I want something like https://istio.io/blog/2019/proxy/ but for the same domain as istio is behind, so I need to route to a public IP

Answer (score 0):

Based on that [istio discuss](https://discuss.istio.io/t/istio-egress-breaking-apache-httpd-reverse-proxy/3542/9)

User @palic asked a question here

> Shouldn’t it be possible to let ISTIO do the reverse proxy
>   thing, so that no one needs a webserver (httpd/nginx/
>   lighthttpd/…) to do the reverse proxy job?

And the answer provided by @Daniel_Watrous

> The job of the Istio control plane is to configure a fleet of reverse proxies. The purpose of the webserver is to serve content, not reverse proxy. The reverse proxy technology at the heart of Istio is Envoy, and Envoy can be use as a replacement for HAProxy, nginx, Apache, F5, or any other component that is being used as a reverse proxy.

---

So if we talk about reverse proxy, you need to use other technology than istio itself.

As far as I'm concerned, you could use some nginx pod, which would be configured as reverse proxy, and it will be the host for your virtual service.

So it would look like in below example.

**EXAMPLE**

Virtual Service -> Service -> Nginx Pod -> get resource from outside of the cluster using proxy_pass

Comment: > Envoy can be use as a replacement for HAProxy, nginx ...

Which is what I'd like to do =)